# Drag and Drop from 2 listwidgets , but change text after dropping in 2nd ListWidget

Tags: c++, qt

[image]

The 'Country' QListwidget is going to be populated with country names items and if the user drags that an item and drops it in capital QListWidget, it should show me the name of its capital , i.e that item text should change in capital QListWidget.

for example - an item named "Russia" in country listwidget , after dragging and dropping , the item should be renamed to "Moscow".

so far to enable drag and drop, i have just written this code,

```
ui->country_listwidget->setDragEnabled(true);
```

`ui->capital_listwidget->setAcceptDrops(true);`

is this possible in QT ?

Comment: "is this possible in QT ?" - Yes.

Comment: oh, thanks, how can i achieve it, what steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to create 2 roles that store each information, and then use a delegate to display the text depending on the view:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

enum CustomRoles {
    CounrtyRole = Qt::UserRole,
    CapitalRole
};

class DisplayDelegate: public QStyledItemDelegate{
public:
    DisplayDelegate(int displayRole=Qt::DisplayRole, QObject *parent=nullptr)
        :QStyledItemDelegate(parent), m_displayRole(displayRole){}
    int getDisplayRole() const{
        return m_displayRole;
    }
    void setDisplayRole(int value){
        m_displayRole = value;
    }
protected:
    void initStyleOption(QStyleOptionViewItem *option, const QModelIndex &index) const{
        QStyledItemDelegate::initStyleOption(option, index);
        QVariant value = index.data(m_displayRole);
        if (value.isValid() && !value.isNull()) {
            option->features |= QStyleOptionViewItem::HasDisplay;
            option->text = displayText(value, option->locale);
        }
    }
private:
    int m_displayRole;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QListWidget *country_lw = new QListWidget;
    country_lw->setItemDelegate(new DisplayDelegate(CounrtyRole));
    QListWidget *capital_lw = new QListWidget;
    capital_lw->setItemDelegate(new DisplayDelegate(CapitalRole));

    country_lw->setDragEnabled(true);
    capital_lw->setAcceptDrops(true);

    QListWidgetItem *item1 = new QListWidgetItem;
    item1->setData(CounrtyRole, "Country1");
    item1->setData(CapitalRole, "Capital1");
    country_lw->addItem(item1);
    QListWidgetItem *item2 = new QListWidgetItem;
    item2->setData(CounrtyRole, "Country2");
    item2->setData(CapitalRole, "Capital2");
    country_lw->addItem(item2);
    QListWidgetItem *item3 = new QListWidgetItem;
    item3->setData(CounrtyRole, "Country3");
    item3->setData(CapitalRole, "Capital3");
    country_lw->addItem(item3);


    QWidget w;
    QHBoxLayout *lay = new QHBoxLayout(&w);
    lay->addWidget(country_lw);
    lay->addWidget(capital_lw);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: This is Indeed the simplest and most efficient way i guess, You Sir, are a genius.